# How to use `list` to locate attributes changed to `s---ia-------`?

Tags: linux, find, attributes

My linux CentOS server has been compromised lately (rootkit). Some files attributes have been changed, for example the command :

`lsattr /bin/ls`

gives

`s---ia------- /bin/ls`

How cand I use `find` command to list all files on system that have attributes set to `s---ia-------` instead of `-------------`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find doesn't have any way of obtaining this information directly but you don't need to use it as lsattr has a `-R` switch so

```
lsattr -R /path/you/care/about 2>/dev/null | grep -- 's---ia-------'
```

should do what you want.

Note the `--` to grep isn't required for your specific set of attributes but if for example you wanted to search for '----ia-------' then you would definitely need it.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have mentioned about find, I am suggesting you to try following command

```
find / -type f -exec lsattr {} + | grep -v '\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-\-'
```

Ideally, I'd prefer to use [AIDE](http://aide.sourceforge.net/) or [tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/)

Comment: Doesn't work: "missing argument to -exec".

Comment: I have verified and it works on CentOS 5. I forgot to mention escape character  for grep though. it should be | grep -v '\-\-......'

Comment: You can use `--` to indicate that there are no more options